# VS10 IDE cannot find referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I should preface this question by stating that I am (potentially) inheriting a project that is somewhere around 85% complete. After witnessing successful execution, the full solution was transferred to my machine where I have been struggling to get it running again.

Having made no changes prior, the IDE gives me the following error message:

`The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

This is in spite of clearly seeing the assembly referenced beneath the reference node. I've attempted unattaching, rebuilding, and reattaching the offending assemblies to no avail.

I have explored a variety of options as suggested by other users for similar issues without finding a solution.

What are some potential causes of this and what solutions can I explore?

Comment: Did you changed the target framework recently?

Comment: MOst likely the assembly you're referencing is out of sync with the code you're working on.  Perhaps  you've got a copy of the referenced assembly that was written before the Infrastructure namespace existed in it.  Do you have the actual code for the referenced assembly?

Comment: My crystal ball says: "Change the project's Target Framework setting from the Client Profile to the full version".

Comment: I know that is one of the most common mistakes, but I have checked and the Target Framework is set to full 4.0 on each assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE is probably not set `Target Framework`:

To change the targeted .NET Framework version in an existing project

1. Open the project you want to change.
2. In the Solution Explorer toolbar, choose the Properties button.
3. You can also select the project node in Solution Explorer, open the
   context menu (by right-clicking the node), and select Properties.
4. You should see the settings on the Application tab. If you do not,
   select it.
5. In the Target Framework dropdown list, choose the .NET Framework
   version that you want. Then click the OK button.

The project unloads and then reloads. It now targets the framework version that you just selected.

Comment: Please improve your answer. It's hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks, but all assemblies had been previously set to full 4.0 framework. I have double checked a few times now for certainty.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem add in a `USING` line in the source file.

Comment: Actually, the `Using` line is one of the areas where I'm getting the error.

Comment: You have the wrong syntax for the using line then.  Remove the MyProject prefix.

Comment: @Hogan No, Target Framework is probably the cause of this error.